# How to stack annotations into the margin?

Tags: footnotes, marginpar

I defined `\tnote{...}` and use it a lot in my text. When I am in draft mode this should print `...` into the margin in a tiny font. In final mode nothing should appear.

The current version I have is defined thusly:

```
\newcommand{\tnote}[1]{\tikz[overlay] \node at (0ex,2pt) [font=\tiny,anchor=north west,text=blue] {#1};}
```

This prints a tiny blue text below the place where `\tnote` appears when used like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply \tnote{note1} dummy text of \tnote{note2} the
printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
```

Sometimes I have paragraphs that only consist of notes. This (alas) creates an empty white space with all notes overprinting each other:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the.

\tnote{note1} \tnote{note2}

Printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the.
```

Now I have three issues:

- Instead of text below the like I'd like it to be placed **besides the text**. It does not have to be in the regular TeX "margin" (there is such a thing, I believe). It is only draft notes I need.
- Sometimes I have lines only with notes. Then I have nasty empty paragraphs the way I do it. The **extra vertical white space** should disappear.
- In this case the notes should be **stacked**, so each one stays readable. It would be ok to reserve a special area on a page where they accumulate like footnotes but that sounds more complicated then to have them automatically arranged inside the margin. I have no idea how to do either.

Comment: Have a look at the `\marginpar` (that's the standard thing that puts notes into the margins). Also there is the `marginnote`-package (but `\marginpar` seems to be better suited in your case).

Comment: Also: If those are only for editorial purpose, why don't you put comments with `%TODO:` in your .tex-files (most editors highlight those)?

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do this would be:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\newcommand{\tnote}[1]{\ifdraft{\marginpar{\tiny\color{blue}#1}}{}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\tnote{test1}

\tnote{test2}

\tnote{test3} \tnote{test4}

No empty space added. The notes are stacked nicely -- with a warning during
compilation.
\end{document}
```

This way the `\tnote` command does nothing if you didn't pass the `draft`-option, if you passed it the contents will be placed into the margin in blue color.
[image]

Comment: `marginpar`... I thought I already did but had difficulties. I try it out again and will come back after the test.

Comment: @towi depending on your document the placement can be a bit odd. This might be caused by the `geometry`-package if you don't specify the `marginparwidth` and `marginparsep` options.